# LibVLCSharp not running when loaded in a form

Tags: c#, libvlcsharp

I have a basic C# program in VS2022 to load and play a video using LibVLCSharp. When I use it as the main form in the program, everything works well.

If I use the same code in a form that is created and opened from the main form, nothing works - the video does not play and events are not fired.

What is stopping the video from playing when the form is not the main form?

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to say without the code. What did you try? which version? which framework? winForms? Do you have any logs?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a perfect place to discuss technical problems. It would be great if you could share some code.